# I copied the example function on Firebase page and in my console and I'm seeing this error message any ideas?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions

When i write this google cloud function:

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun((context) => {
  console.log('This will be run every 5 minutes!');
});
```

I get the error **"Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value"** in my firebase console

Im i wrong in thinking that this function should be logging to my console every 5 mins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're actually asking how to resolve this error, add `return null` to the end of the function.

Comment: Thank youu so much